# How to get references to already instantiated remote objects using WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, migration, remoting

I’ve just read Ingo Rammer's article titled “From .NET Remoting to the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)”, on the MSDN website (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730857(v=vs.80).aspx).

I still have one doubt, though, and I hope someone can help me.

In session “Step 3 - Use Sessions instead of Client-Activated Objects”, which covers exactly the kind of use of Remoting we make here in our company, he has shown how to obtain and use references to remote objects instantiated on the other side (server’s side). However, in our case, we don’t instantiate these objects on the server’s side at the moment the client requests references to them. The objects already exist on the server’s side (they were previously instantiated), and I just want to get references to these already active objects.

How do we do this today, using Remoting? We have an “Object Server” object (which derives from MarshalByRefObject). This object is available through an URL “tcp://localhost:9002/ObjectServerInstance”. Remote applications can get a reference to it using Activator.GetObject. This Object Server object implements an interface IObjectServer, that declares a method with the following signature:
Object GetObject (string objTag);

Client applications use the reference to this Object Server object to call its GetObject method, passing an object tag string as parameter (Ex: “Portfolio”). This method then returns a reference to the Portfolio object, which has previously published itself before the Object Server object using this tag “Portfolio”. The Portfolio object also derives from MarshalByRefObject, of course. And it isn’t instantiated only when a remote client asks for a reference to it, it was already instantiated on the server.

Of course, this could be done differently. Each object that might be accessed remotely could programmatically use its own objectUri to publish itself before the Remoting layer on the server’s side (Ex: “tcp://localhost:9002/MyObjectInstance”), and on the clients’ side we could use Activator.GetObject directly to get each object’s reference. But this is irrelevant to the point I’m raising. Anyway, the server objects would already exist when they publish themselves before the Remoting layer.

Was I clear enough? Do you see a way to do this using WCF?

Comment: The objects on the server side aren't used ONLY on the clients' side. The server is an application that is already running. The same objects on the server can and must be accessed by multiple clients. For example: I have and object on the server side that is an order manager for the security MSFT (Microsoft). Every client that wants to send orders for the MSFT security must send the requests to this order manager, and after executing some internal code, this order manager then sends the requested order to the proper exchange (Ex: NYSE or NASDAQ).

Comment: I do not have control WHEN the client apps will request references to these order manager objects. The only requirement is that the server app must be up and the order manager objects must be instantiated when the first client asks for a reference to send an order. And all clients that want to send orders for the SAME security, like MSFT, will access the SAME object on the server's side.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code at the link you provided, it seems to me that you need to modify the `GetInstanceMethod` implementation of the `IRemoteFactory` interface to *return an existing object,* instead of creating a new one.

```
public interface IRemoteFactory
{
  IMySessionBoundObject GetInstance();
}

public class RemoteFactory : MarshalByRefObject, IRemoteFactory
{
  public IMySessionBoundObject GetInstance()
  {
    // Return an already existing object, instead of a new one.
    return MyAlreadyExistingSessionBoundObject;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right if you're using Remoting. But my question is how to do this using WCF. In this same example, when he migrates the code to WCF, anyway he uses ChannelFactory<IMySessionBoundObject>.CreateChannel() to get new instances of the MySessionBoundObject objects. He changes the IMySessionBoundObject RemoteFactory.GetInstance() method to EndpointAddress10 GetInstanceAddress(), and uses some artifices to get the references to the real objects, but I think anyway the objects are being instantiated at the time the ChannelFactory<IMySessionBoundObject>.CreateChannel() method is called.

Comment: Your insistence on using pre-made objects seems to be at odds with the WCF philosophy that objects on the server side live only as long as the session.  *"A session does not usually span multiple services, but is instead only valid in the communication with a single service instance. It just means that you will talk with the same server-side object for the lifetime of your client-side proxy."*  Seems like you would need another object that only lives during the session lifetime, but knows how to communicate with your preexisting objects server-side.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. I can't have my persistent objects on the server side as my service instances. I'll have to create service instances of another type every time a client wants to call my persistent objects' methods. An these service instances have to know how to communicate with the local persistent objects. Is that it? If this is correct, isn't that less efficient then using Remoting to call the remote persistent objects' methods? Using Remoting I don't have to create a new communication channel each time, the channel remains opened. Also, there is no intermediary.

Comment: Just updating: [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)] attribute does not solve my problem, for two main reasons: 1) Once again, my server side persistent objects cannot be instantiated the first time a client creates a channel, they already exist before any client connects; 2) My objects are not Singletons, I can have multiple objects of the same class instantiated (Ex: Multiple Portfolio objects for multiple securities).

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to your problem, but be warned it goes against the grain of WCF and the concepts of service orientation.

Maintaining a sessionful state on the server has all sorts of ramifications and potential pitfalls.  You introduce coupling between the client(s) and the server and have to think carefully what you will do in the case of corrupt state and exceptions.

The solution is a bit too long for a Stack Overflow post, so I've posted it on github [here](https://github.com/lozengivity/WcfSharedSession).

I can't claim any credit for the solution - most of it comes from a blog post I read somewhere (I'll update this once I remember what it was).  It is interesting from the point of view that it uses some fairly advanced WCF low-level code - and it great for furthering your understanding on how WCF works.

I would further iterate that if there is anyway of avoiding implementing this in a production environment to go down that route.